# SQL MariaDB - Loop this query for every table in every database with exceptions

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, innodb

I have large databases that I prune on a monthly basis using the query below. However, I have hundreds of tables and would like to make this into a foreach loop for each table in the databases.

I know how to achieve this loop in PHP but would be great to have it in pure SQL to run directly as a query on the database.

The tables prefixed with `noprune` such as `noprune_master_tableZ` need to be left out of the loop.

Where do I begin? Thanks

```
START TRANSACTION;
set @N := (now());
CREATE TABLE master_tableA_snapshot AS SELECT * FROM master_tableA where insertDATE < date_sub(@N,INTERVAL 32 DAY);
SELECT * from master_tableA_snapshot INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/master_tableA_snapshot_TODAYSDATE.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
DELETE from master_tableA where insertDATE < date_sub(@N,INTERVAL 32 DAY);
DROP TABLE master_tableA_snapshot;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: DDL statements like `DROP TABLE` are an explicit `COMMIT` so your transaction isn't doing much. What did you want it to do? Why not `SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE` directly rather than the temp table? PHP is pretty good at scripting things, while its possible to put into MySQL events its harder to debug and maintain.

Comment: Hi Dan, I thought because I write into master_tableA very frequently I had to wrap this all in a transaction? I would be inserting into master_tableA during the SELECT command

Comment: Transactions are more commiting multiple things at once. I assume you aren't inserting 32+ day old dates. so it won't make a difference. At the the repeatable read isolation level (default) it won't make a difference either because the `DELETE` statement will see exactly the same data that the `SELECT` saw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've really only got two statements with a helper variable simplified as:

```
set @N := date_sub(NOW(),INTERVAL 32 DAY);

SELECT *
FROM master_tableA
WHERE insertDATE < @N
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/master_tableA_snapshot_TODAYSDATE.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

DELETE from master_tableA where insertDATE < @N;
```

PHP select table names with a query:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE SCHEMA='mydatabase'
  AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'noprune%';
```